# ¿Por que no me genera el for dentro de la tabla?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una función en js que me genera una tabla de multiplicar dentro de un div, dependiendo del número que le pasan al input hará la tabla de un número u otro. El problema está en que no me genera el conetido dentro de la tabla y no entiendo el porque. Este es mi código .js:

```
function inici() {
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",generarTabla);
    var div = document.getElementById("resultado");

    function generarTabla() {
        var numero=document.getElementById("input").value;

        div.innerHTML += "<table>";
        div.innerHTML += "<tr> Tabla del "+numero+"</tr>";
        for(var i=0;i<=10;i++) {
            div.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+numero+"*"+i+"="+numero*i+"</td></tr>";
        }
        div.innerHTML += "</table>";


    }
}

window.onload=inici;
```

Y este mi HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tabla_multiplicar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" name="" id="input">
    <button id="button"> Enviar </button>
    <div id="resultado">
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
No leí bien tu pregunta y por lo tanto te respondí mal.

No te genera la tabla porque estas actualizando directamente la variable `innerHTML` y al hacer lo siguiente `div.innerHTML += "<table>";` el navegador automáticamente cierra el tag `<table></table>` al insertarlo en el DOM y por eso todo lo que viene después lo trata como string.

Tienes que crear el html de la [tabla](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) en una variable local y cuando lo tengas tienes que asignarlo así  `div.innerHTML = table;` y el navegador ya se encargará de parsear el string a nodos de html.

```js
  function inici() {
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", generarTabla);
    var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

    function generarTabla() {
      var numero = document.getElementById("input").value;
      let tabla = `<table>
            <thead>
            <tr><th>Tabla del ${numero}</th></tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
        `;
      for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        tabla += `<tr><td>${numero}*${i}=${numero*i}</td></tr>`;
      }
      tabla += `</tbody></table>`;
      resultado.innerHTML = tabla;
    }
  }

  window.onload = inici;
```

```html
<input type="number" name="" id="input">
<button id="button"> Enviar </button>
<div id="resultado">

</div>
```

He usado *template literals* que te permiten concatenar variables. Puedes leer [más aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Y otra cosa es lo que comenta @facu aquino es mejor poner tu script de javascript al final de todo para no tener problemas de elementos `null`.
Aunque en tu caso, ejecutas el código en el evento [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) funciona bien porque este evento se ejecuta cuando ya se ha parseado el html, javascript y se han cargado todos los recursos(imágenes, css...);

Comment: Hago que el boton ejecute sea funcion al pulsarse.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: @Marc si te sirvió la respuesta márcala como aceptada porfavor.

Answer (score 0):

tenes que poner el `script` antes del cierre del `html` sino estas intentando tomar un elemendo del DOM antes que se pinte en el mismo y va a dar error

```js
function inici() {
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",generarTabla);
    var div = document.getElementById("resultado");

    function generarTabla() {
        var numero=document.getElementById("input").value;

        div.innerHTML += "<table>";
        div.innerHTML += "<tr> Tabla del "+numero+"</tr>";
        for(var i=0;i<=10;i++) {
            div.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+numero+"*"+i+"="+numero*i+"</td></tr>";
        }
        div.innerHTML += "</table>";


    }
}

window.onload=inici;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" name="" id="input">
    <button id="button"> Enviar </button>
    <div id="resultado">
        
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tabla_multiplicar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```